# In a RadListView, how to remove extra space between item columns?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Whith a RadListView and grid or staggered layout, how can I achieve that on the sides the margin is the same as the space between two columns:

```
|screen edge                     screen edge|
|                                           |
|20px |------------|20px |------------|20px |
|     |item1       |     |item2       |     |
|     |            |     |            |     |
|     |            |     |            |     |
|     |            |     |            |     |
|     |------------|     |------------|     |
|                                           |
```

Answer (score 0):

*For Android:*

Code-behind:

```
myRadListView.androidListView.setPadding(10,0,10,0);
```

CSS:

```
.my-list-item {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

This is not really elegant but it works for me.